# Cycle of digraph with 16 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple digraph with $16$ vertices. Suppose that any $10$ vertices of $G$ form a cycle of length $10$. Prove that any $11$ vertices of $G$ also form a cycle of length $11$.

Is this a special case from a general result?